# Active Reports: Copy paste issue

Tags: activereports

I have generated a report in active reports.
After the report is dispayed in the report viewer, I copied the report by clicking on the Copy button and tried to paste in a word document.

I have some horizontal lines in my report, when I check the copied data in word, the horizntal lines are over lapping on some of the text dispalyed in report.

Is there any way to overcome this problem?

I have attached the screen shot of the report's actual layout and the issue I am facing after pasting the report layout in a word document.

Regards,
Sujata

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Please do add code . . and seems the image is not attached as well.

Comment: Hi,I have not written any code for copy. I am just using the default copy button available in the reprt viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please send your RPX/RDLX file to ComponentOne support using ComponentOne [support forum](http://our.componentone.com/groups/forum/reporting/activereports-8/) or support E-Mail address supportone@componentone.com? In the meanwhile you may use the following options to get the desired results.

1. If you are using ActiveReports 8 then you can use the activate the snapshot mode in the viewer, select the content from viewer and this will create an image of the selection. You can later paste image this in Word, Paint, Excel etc. Since this is an image it will be obviously not editable.
2. If you are looking to get editable content, then you may make use of the RtfExport filter available in ActiveReports.

Hope this helps.